# Get better error messages from `[[<-.data.frame`

Tags: r, shiny, error-handling

A have a very big Shinyapp and at some point I get an error message:

```
Warning: Error in [[<-.data.frame: Ersetzung hat 1 Zeile, Daten haben 0
  3: runApp
  2: print.shiny.appobj
  1: <Anonymous>
```

I do not know how to make the messages appear in English, it means replacement has 1 row, data 0.

I think I have surrounded all the commands I use to alter a `data.frame` using the `df[[col]] <-` technique with try-functions so I should be able to find out where the error is but I did not find it. Since my app is pretty big I cannot be sure if I forgot one call. My code base is pretty big and uses libraries that I have not written myself, but I asked myself whether it is possible to override the classic `[[<-.data.frame`-function with my own custom function that does exactly the same but provides better error messages. Is there a way to do that?

Here is a small piece of code that recreates the error which gives me no chance knowing where it came from:

```
df <- iris[iris$Sepal.Length>5000,]
makeNewCol <- function(df, newCol="newCol"){
  df[[newCol]] <- 42
  df
}


library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn","Btn")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn,{
    print(makeNewCol(df))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In general I would be very happy to find out about any options that take the same code (especially in a shiny-app) and provide better error messages.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong approach in my (deleted) answer. The use of German in an error message suggests that somehow the shiny server or the browser are suggesting the different language. On your console, check `Sys.getenv("LANG")` and confirm something like `"en_US.UTF-8"`, then run that in the shiny app as well. Also in shiny, check `session$request$HEADERS["accept-language"]` (and/or `session$request$HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`), my guess is that one of them will different from "en"glish.

Comment: To get more insight into headers and env-vars that might influence this problem, you can use my [r-shiny-clientdata (gist)](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/6557222782dbb7cd4aaee1b62dc0b455) shiny app for quick insight.